# Tensor product and injective maps

Tags: commutative-algebra

during a class we met a map $\Phi : \mathbb{Z}^n\to \mathbb{Z}^n$. We saw that $\Phi\otimes 1_\mathbb{Q}$ was an isomorphism and then the Professor said that it implied that $\Phi$ was injective. Unfortunately, I am not sure about the reason for this and I wanted to ask you if you may help me to understand it. I have doubts because I was studying on my own commutative algebra and saw that I may have two modules $M'\subset M$, $N$ and an inclusion $i: M'\to M$, but $i\otimes 1: M'\otimes N\to M\otimes N$ may not be not injective ($M'=2\mathbb{Z}$, $M=\mathbb{Z}$, $N=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and consider the element $2\otimes x=0 \in \mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, $\neq 0 \in 2\mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$). So I understood that tensor product should be considered carefully in both direction: $\Phi\otimes 1_\mathbb{Q}$ injective => $\Phi$ injective; $\Phi$ injective => $\Phi\otimes 1_\mathbb{Q}$ injective. I was wondering whether there is an object that measure the problem in both direction. I thank you in advance if you may help with the first part of this question, the second or both. Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: the fundamental fact here is that $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is *free*.

The canonical map $\def\Z{\mathbb{Z}}\def\Q{\mathbb{Q}}\Z\to\Q$ is injective and you can identify $\Q$ with $\Z\otimes\Q$. But the tensor product commutes with direct sums, so $\Z^n\to\Z^n\otimes\Q$ is injective too.

It's just a check seeing that the diagram
$$
\begin{array}{c}
\Z^n & \xrightarrow{\Phi} & \Z^n \\
\downarrow && \downarrow \\
\Z^n\otimes\Q & \xrightarrow{\Phi_{\Q}} & \Z^n\otimes\Q
\end{array}
$$
is commutative.

There are other cases in which tensoring by $\Q$ reflects monomophisms (it always preserves them because $\Q$ is torsion-free, hence flat), but at a first stage a direct proof using freeness of $\Z^n$ seems better.

Comment: Hint 2: a free module is always flat. ;-)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your hints. Unfortunately, I cannot arrive to a conclusion because I think that there are some topics that I don't know and that I should study. Could you suggest me some books that together with your hints may help me to solve this problem? Thank you very much..

Comment: @ egreg: Thank you very much for your detailed explaination and your help. You have been very clear. I would like to ask you just an advice for further information: I believe that in the end of you answer you are referring to the Tor functor, am I right? Could you recommend me a book about it? Thank you.

Comment: @JohnN. Hilton-Stammbach, “A course on homological algebra” (maybe a bit dated).

Comment: @ egreg: thanks for the advice. I will look at it.

Comment: You don't have to read anything about flatness etc. in order to understand the injectivity ...

Answer (score 4):

Use the commutative diagram

$\begin{array}{c} \mathbb{Z}^n & \xrightarrow{\Phi} & \mathbb{Z}^m \\ \downarrow && \downarrow \\ \mathbb{Q}^n & \xrightarrow{\Phi_{\mathbb{Q}}} & \mathbb{Q}^m. \end{array}$

Since $\Phi_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is an injective and $\mathbb{Z}^n \to \mathbb{Q}^n$ is injective, it follows that $\Phi$ is injective.

Comment: Thanks for your time spent answering my question. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Martin, Would you explain commutativity of the diagram shortly please? How it is commutative ? please explain using maps in the blanks

Answer (score 3):

Write down the short exact sequence

$$ 0 \to \ker \Phi \to \Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{Z} \to \operatorname{coker} \Phi \to 0.$$

The functor $-\otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} \Bbb{Q}$ is exact since $\Bbb{Q}$ is a flat $\Bbb{Z}$-module. Thus if  the tensored map is injective this means that $(\ker \Phi) \otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} \Bbb{Q} = 0$. Now $\ker \Phi$ is a submodule of a free module over a PID and hence is finitely generated. This means $\ker \Phi = T \oplus F$, torsion part plus a free part of finite rank. The torsion part has to be zero as $\Bbb{Z}^n$ is torsion free. So $\ker \Phi \cong \Bbb{Z}^k$ for some $0 \leq k \leq n$. But now

$$0 = \ker \Phi \otimes_{\Bbb{Z}}\Bbb{Q} = (\Bbb{Z}^k) \otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} \Bbb{Q} = \Bbb{Q}^k  $$

which implies that $k= 0$, i.e. $\ker \Phi = 0$.

Comment: Thanks to all for answering.

Comment: This proof is *way* too complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Clearly there are some things that I don't know and that I should study in order to fully understand this answer. Could someone suggest me some books that cover the topics explained in Grothendieck's answer?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have been looking for the things I was missing in your answer and eventually I understood it (I didn't know the structure theorem for finitely generated modules over PID). Thanks again.

Comment: You don't really need the structure theorem. All you need is that "Submodules of free modules over a PID are free", which could replace "Now $\ker \Phi$ is a submodule....... as $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is torsion free" in the answer.

Comment: @ Ragib Zaman: Thanks for the help.